# get xml all attributes using jquery

Tags: jquery, xml

I want to get attribute value from a xml file, I am using following code to get attribute value:

```
var result=$(xml).find("segment[id=1]").attr("name");
```

But as it's definition of attr, it is returning only first value. I need all attrib values, I have studied about .each() function in xml parsing. But I failed to get all attributes.
xml is following :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <code_gen>
     <segment id="1" name="POS">POS.txt</segment>
     <segment id="1" name="On_Off">on_off.txt</segment>
     <segment id="1" name="Sellert">seller.txt</segment>
     <segment id="1" name="Cross_Border">cross.txt</segment>
     <segment id="1" name="NA">NA.txt</segment>
    </code_gen>
```

Comment: This question is unanswerable without seeing your XML.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan question updated

Comment: Your XML is a little odd. Why have multiple duplicate `id` attributes instead of `<code_gen><segment id="1"><item name="POS">...</item></segment>`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.map()` along with `.get()` to get all the name attribute in the format of an array

Try,

```
var allNames = $(xml)
                 .find("segment[id=1]")
                   .map(function(){ 
                     return $(this).attr('name'); 
                   }).get();
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `.each()` to iterate over multiple elements in matched selector:

```
 var allName=[];
 $(xml).find("segment[id=1]").each(function(){
    allName.push($(this).attr("name"));
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

Vanilla JS

```
var atr = document.getElementById("someId").attributes;
var arr = [];
for (var i=0, l=atr.length; i<l; i++){
//    arr.push(atr.item(i).nodeName); // attribute name
    arr.push(atr.item(i).nodeValue); // attribute value
}
```

JQuery

```
 var attributes = {}; 
$('#some_id')[0].attributes.each(function( index, attr ) {
                attributes[ attr.name ] = attr.value;
            });
```